# MultiJson::DecodeError unexpected token at {"email":"foo@bar.com"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, callback

I'm developing a new Ruby on Rails 3.2 application.
This application will receive a periodic json callback with statistics.
The callback i receive is not entirely valid. The json rules are separated by newlines.

> The callback POSTs have a content-type header of application/json, and contain exactly one JSON string per line, with each line representing one event. Please note that currently the POST headers define this post as application/json, though it’s not; each line is a valid JSON string, but the overall POST body is not. For example:

This is a example of the callback:

```
{"email":"foo@bar.com","timestamp":1322000095,"unique_arg":"my unique arg","event":"delivered"}
{"email":"foo@bar.com","timestamp":1322000097,"unique_arg":"my unique arg","event":"click"}
{"email":"foo@bar.com","timestamp":1322000096,"unique_arg":"my unique arg","event":"open"}
```

When i receive this callback my Rails application crashes with a "MultiJson::DecodeError"

> > 743: unexpected token at '{"email":"foo@bar.com","timestamp":1322000096,"unique_arg":"my unique arg","event":"open"}'

I think the application detects the application/json header and try automatic to parse it.
How can i convert this to a valid JSON object, so i can use this in my controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Put 
gem 'yajl-ruby' in Gemfile and
require 'yajl/json_gem' config/application.rb

Comment: this works, but i don't get why i was getting the error in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

In gem file declare
 gem 'yajl-ruby'
 It is used to Parse and encode multiple JSON objects to and from streams or strings continuous.

And require 'yajl/json_gem' in application.rb

Answer (score 1):

Put Elements in Brackets:

```
   [{"email":"foo@bar.com","timestamp":1322000095,"unique_arg":"my unique arg","event":"delivered"},
    {"email":"foo@bar.com","timestamp":1322000097,"unique_arg":"my unique arg","event":"click"},
    {"email":"foo@bar.com","timestamp":1322000096,"unique_arg":"my unique arg","event":"open"}]`
```

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce your problem by copy-and-pasting the error message token using both ActiveSupport::JSON.decode and MultiJson.decode in a Rails shell. Rails 3.2.1

Any other clues?

Answer (score -1):

This issue is likely due to response body encoded in ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8. Possible fix on client side is be convert it back to UTF-8 using ruby 'iconv' encoding methods.